# C++ math.h on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: c++, macos, g++, math.h

I have a C++ program that will not compile under OS X 10.8.5 with the g++ compiler. The problem seems to be with the math.h header file.

This is the version of g++ is

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Users/densmore3/local/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
 Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20141029/configure --enable-   languages=c++,fortran
 Thread model: posix
 gcc version 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

There are 40-50 errors of the type below. The code compiled fine on 10.6. What is going on?

```
/Users/xxxx/local/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/include-fixed/math.h:203:1: error: ‘__header_always_inline’ does not name a type
__header_always_inline int __inline_isfinitef(float);

Users/densmore3/local/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/include-fixed/math.h:580:27: error: expected initializer before ‘__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_0_DEP__MAC_10_9’
extern float __inff(void) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
```

Here is a piece of test code that gives the same error as my real code. The error goes away if I remove the math.h include statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <complex>
//#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The compile command I am using is:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

Comment: What compile commands are you using?

Comment: I added additional information to the original post.

Comment: What happens if you #include <cmath> instead of <math.h>?

Comment: Is that a clean install, or did you upgrade to 10.8.5 after installing gcc?

Comment: Including cmath results in the same errors.

Comment: I have reinstalled gcc, and tried different versions, with no change in the error. This is a work computer and is managed by the IT folks; I'm not sure, but I think it was an upgrade to 10.8.5.

Comment: The version of `g++` you are using is not the default for `10.8.5`. It should be using: `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`. Where are you installing the `g++` you are currently using from?

Comment: I'm using the gcc tools from here, http://hpc.sourceforge.net/. I use my code on linux and wanted to use the same compiler for both linux and mac versions. That is why I'm not using the default mac stuff.

Comment: `gcc` compiled and built for `osx` wouldn't be the same as on `linux` regardless. Unless there's a compelling reason to use a non-standard prerelease version then stick with what works; otherwise you'll need to understand how to control the dialect of `C++` when compiling.

Comment: The website you link to says that their version of gcc-4.9 is for a more recent version of macosx than what you have. You will need to get gcc from somewhere else, or install an older version of gcc.

Comment: Doh.... I had it stuck in my head that 10.8 was Mavericks. Using gcc version 4.8 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc-4.8` is the correct version to use on OS X 10.8.